# Is store.db an SQL database?

Tags: spotlight

Is /.Spotlight-V100/Store-V2/${STORE_UUID}/store.db an SQL database that can be queried with a normal SQL client?

The format is here:

https://github.com/libyal/dtformats/blob/main/documentation/Apple%20Spotlight%20store%20database%20file%20format.asciidoc

Comment: What does `file /.Spotlight-V100/Store-V2/${STORE_UUID}/store.db` say?

Comment: Seems I also don't have that file on Monterey. I need to find the new location too

Comment: `${STORE_UUID}` needs to be replaced by the actual UUID (or by `*` if you don't know it). But doesn't the page you link to already answer the question?

Answer (score 1):

On Monterey the file is in `/System/Volumes/Data/.Spotlight-V100/Store-V2/*/store.db`. Running `file .../store.db` returns `data` so it for sure is not a sqlite database.

PS: As already mentioned in your question, the format is described in [Apple Spotlight store database file format](https://github.com/libyal/dtformats/blob/main/documentation/Apple%20Spotlight%20store%20database%20file%20format.asciidoc).

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not in itself an "SQL Database" (whatever that would mean) - and no, it cannot be queried with a "normal" SQL client. The file format is entirely proprietary.

It is in theory possible to create client software for the those types of data files, so that it could be queried using SQL. I am not aware of any such software existing in the public.